# Monitor database in JAX-RS server

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jersey, jax-rs

I'm writing an app that sends HTTP messages to a JAX-RS/Jersey server with a backing database.

When the server receives a request from a client, it stores some data in the database (id, timestamp, etc). Then it should wait for a certain interval to see if other similar requests come in:

```
SERVER receives a request:
  --> DB insertion 
  --> "observes" the DB for 3 sec for a similar request to come in
  --> if it does, send response immediately
  --> otherwise, send response at timeout
```

Can I observe the database to see if another client's data is inserted before the 3 seconds timeout? If so, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Prevent a single client from making multiple, closely-timed requests or to prevent similar data from being inserted into the db by multiple clients?

Comment: hi user463324, I would like to send a different response to client1 if a similar request has arrived from a client2. But maybe I don't even need a database for that - maybe I could just let the responding threads communicate between them?